# "Who am I and what are my rights?" API in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

On-prem TFS 2017u2. Question - is there a REST API that returns some information about the current user's identity? E. g. ID, username, groups she might be in, permissions, OAuth scopes (if coming through OAuth).

EDIT: looks like there's a bunch of profile related API endpoints that are in VSTS, but not in TFS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the current user profile with below REST API in On-premise TFS:

```
GET http://SERVER:8080/tfs/_api/_common/GetUserProfile?__v=5
```

But not including the groups, permissions, OAuth scopes etc in the response.

However you can [View permissions for yourself or others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/view-permissions) from web portal.

You can also use the VS extension [**TFS Permission Visualizer**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KonstantinErman.TFSPermissionVisualizer) to see the groups, permissions etc.  It displays TFS security groups and permissions in a form of a graph.

Alternatively you can get Groups Users Permissions using TFS API, see [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/09/30/tfs-sdk-get-groups-users-permissions-using-tfs-api-with.aspx) for details.

[image]